# Get array from input textboxes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, textbox

I've got a form like this:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="name" value="object name"><br>
<input type="text" name="atrib[]" value="atrib name"><input type="text" name="val[]" value="default value"><br>
<input type="text" name="atrib[]" value="atrib name"><input type="text" name="val[]" value="default value"><br>
<input type="text" name="atrib[]" value="atrib name"><input type="text" name="val[]" value="default value"><br>
<div id="fooBar"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add();"><input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="gen();">
</form>
```

With some JavaScript like this:

```
<script>
function add() {
    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");

    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("value", "atrib name");
    element.setAttribute("name", "atrib[]");
    element2.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element2.setAttribute("value", "default value");
    element2.setAttribute("name", "val[]");

    // the div id, where new fields are to be added
    var bar = document.getElementById("bar");

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    bar.appendChild(element);
    bar.appendChild(element2);
    bar.innerHTML += "<br>";
}

function gen() {
    var inputAtrib = document.getElementsByName("atrib[]").value;
    var inputVal = document.getElementsByName("val[]").value;
    alert(inputAtrib);
    alert(inputVal);
}
</script>
```

What I need to do is retrieve both `atrib[]` and `val[]` arrays when a user clicks on generate `onclick="gen();"` button in order to loop trough them and perform some operations. When trying to do so, `inputAtrib` and `inputVal` return `undefined`. I wasn't able to find an easy answer for this, please, could you help me to find the right road to the solution of this problem?

Comment: I tried something like `document.getElementsByName("atrib").value` without any luck, it returns `undefined`

Comment: because your name attribute is not `atrib` but `atrib[]`

Comment: using `atrib[]` returns undefined as well. Also, I don't understand why the downvote. I've done my research and found nothing about this. I found a lot of useful information for retrieving data from normal inputs, but anything about arrays >.<

Comment: because this is not how you ask questions. "here is my markup, i want this and this. go and show me the code" is not how you ask on SO, show the code that you've tried and that does not work

Comment: I wasn't asking at all to write the code for me, I want to understand how should I do this and wanted some tips for puting myself on the road to the solution...

Comment: well, you say that now but look at your question again, sounds a little different :)

Comment: Question edited, sorry if it sounded rude!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is on the right track. It's just that you're using the `document.getElementsByName` slightly wrong. From the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)(emphasis is mine):

> The `getElementsByName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified name (the value of the name attribute), as a **NodeList** object.

So in your code where you do:

```
document.getElementsByName("atrib[]") //This returns a NodeList object
```

In other words, this would be an array of elements that have the `name` attribute with value 'attrib[]' and therefore you can't just access the `value` attribute of that array, which is why you when you do this:

```
var inputAtrib = document.getElementsByName("atrib[]").value; //You get undefined

console.log(document.getElementsByName("atrib[]")); //This would return a node list and you can see all the matched input elements are returned
```

So you would want to do something like:

```
 var test = document.getElementsByName("atrib[]");
 console.log(test[0].value); //Outputs "atrib name 1"
```

You could also use `document.querySelectorAll("input[name='atrib[]']")`.

I have incorporated both these approaches and made a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f710nvL7/2/) out of it. Feel free to play around with it.

Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot! With your info I managed to do what I wanted to do, I also made a Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/pdu8vLz5/) with the result, if anyone is interested!

Comment: instead of alert every name ,how can we save all the value in an object or array and later alter at once?

Answer (score 0):

My solution. JavaScript code that shows in an alert each input named `atrib` and `val`:

```
<script>
function gen() {
    var o = 0;
    while (o < document.getElementsByName("atrib").length) {
        var inputAtrib = document.getElementsByName("atrib")[o].value;
        var inputVal = document.getElementsByName("val")[o].value;
        alert(inputAtrib);
        alert(inputVal);
        o++;
    }
}
</script>
```